# Output json array in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am a little stuck on how to retrieve all the values from the json array in jquery. I know it needs to be looped but how ? The function -
at the moment is:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'query.php',                     
    data: "",                       
    dataType: 'json',                   
    success: ajaxfunction
   }); 

function ajaxfunction(json_data){
// problem is below, i need to output all the data from the array         
    console.log (json_data)
    while(json_data){
    $('#maindisplay').html("<b>Product: </b>"+json_data.prod_name+"<b> colour: </b>"+json_data.colour); // problem is here, i need to output all the data from the array
    }
  }
```

The php:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fproduct WHERE fproduct.category='Shirts'");
$elements = array ();
do{
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
    if ($row)    //if there is anything
              $elements[] = ($row); 

} while($row);
echo json_encode($elements);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the elements of the array.

```
function ajaxfunction(json_data){
    for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++){
        $('#maindisplay').append($("<b>Product: </b>"+json_data[i].prod_name+"<b> colour: </b>"+json_data[i].colour+"<br>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed it to use `append` instead of `html`. A table would probably be a better way to present it, though.

Comment: Should be `for(var i = 0...`.

Comment: I think you should parse your JSON data before the loop: `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);`

Comment: @juanchopx2 That's done automatically by jQuery when you specify `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: thanks, just wanted to see if it outputs, i was going to style it with tables.